# binary search tree paths

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, search-path

In a binary search tree if you are along a certain search path, what keys are considered to be on the left of the path and which on the right?

For example if my tree is :

```
              25
      12             30
   10    15       28   32
       14  20
```

And lets say my current search path is 20->12->15->20.

1) Are both 10 and 14 considered to be on the left of this search path or is only 10?

2) Also are all 3 numbers 30, 28 and 32 considered on the right of the search path?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant the path `25-12-15-20`, I would say both `10` *and* `14` are left of this path. That's because in order to find either of them, you have to backtrack up the tree (to either `15` or `12`) and take a left branch where the path goes right.

Same deal for the three numbers `30`, `28` and `32`. Since you have to backtrack up to `25` and then go right instead of left, they can be considered on the right of that path:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also love the graphic